# Grab Posts Content from Database with hyperlink - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, hyperlink, anchor

**hello guys,
i want to know how to get content from database with Anchor tag.. as a example i have posted the post on the site.**

```
Hello I am the PHP.go from here http://php.net
```

**now when i get data from the database i want to show php.net as a link.
like this...**

> Hello I am the PHP.go from here http://php.net

**how to do it using php..**

if there have any tutorials,videos related to it.. post here guys.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regular expression`

```
$text = "Hello I am the PHP.go from here http://php.net";
$pattern = "/http:\/\/(www\.)?([^.]+\.[^.\s]+\.?[^.\s]*)/i";
$replace = "<a href='http://\\1\\2'>http://\\1\\2</a>";
$string =  preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$text);
echo $string;
```

Comment: it shows this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pattern' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: $text need semi-colon in the end